# SignalR - failed to process connectionToken - key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: .net, signalr, system.security

I have SignalR application hosted using Windows app. Long story, easier with selfhosting, I know. 
It was working fine - but yesterday, when I run it in Debug mode in Visual Studio, after connection attempt I got an 400 error back `The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.`. 
I looked at the logs - nothing. Then I enabled tracing and found this:

```
SignalR.HubDispatcher Information: 0 : Failed to process connectionToken: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.DpapiDataProtector.ProviderUnprotect(Byte[] encryptedData)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.DataProtectionProviderProtectedData.Unprotect(String protectedValue, String purpose)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.TryGetConnectionId(HostContext context, String connectionToken, String& connectionId, String& message, Int32& statusCode)
```

Any ideas how to fix it? 
I looked at google for an hour - everybody is talking about web farms, certificate stores and load balancers. I don't have any of that, I believe. 
I use .NET 4.5 with SignalR 2.2.1 on Windows 7. Both browser and VS are launched from the same Windows account, if that matters

Comment: Are you setting the connection ID anywhere?

Comment: @AlexDresko you mean on the client?

Comment: @AlexDresko on the server we only read `Context.ConnectionId`

Comment: How many web servers are you running your service on?

Comment: @bsoulier the problem is on my development machine. so one web server

Comment: @bsoulier same happens when we run it in release mode on another computer. in standalone mode, no web-farm or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the issue was (at least in our case) the absense of Redis server which SignalR uses for persistence. After we set it up - the problem went away.
 Not sure how's that connected to machine keys, web farms and encryption in general